# Elegant way to check if either value in a Tuple is nil

Tags: ios, swift, tuples, option-type

I would like to know if anyone has a more elegant way to check if *either* of the values in a Tuple are Nil in Swift?

Currently I'm checking like this:

```
    var credentials = CredentialHelper.getCredentials() //returns a tuple of two Optional Strings.

    if (credentials.username == nil || credentials.password == nil)
    {
        //continue doing work.
    }
```

I would like something more succinct, if possible.

Comment: There's a thread discussing with tuple comparison in Swift and you might want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487519/how-to-elegantly-compare-tuples-in-swift

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with a switch case on the tuple values. For example:

```
func testTuple(input: (String?, String?)) -> String {
    switch input {
    case (_, .None), (.None, _):
        return "One or the other is nil"
    case (.Some(let a), _):
        return "a is \(a)"
    case (_, .Some(let b)):
        return "b is \(b)"
    }
}

testTuple((nil, "B"))  // "One or the other is nil"
testTuple(("A", nil))  // "One or the other is nil"
testTuple(("A", "B"))  // "a is A"
testTuple((nil, nil))  // "One or the other is nil"
```

The trick is to use let bindings on the tuple values.

Answer (score 1):

@Abizern nailed it for cases when you need the whole power of `if case let`. There're situations when you don't, for example, with mapping optionals or using ReactiveCocoa, in which case good old casting comes to help, especially when you need all values and tuples aren't particularly long:

[image]

```
import ReactiveCocoa
import ReactiveSwift

typealias Credentials = (u: String?, p: String?)
var notification = Notification.Name("didReceiveCredentials")

var c1: Credentials? = ("foo", "bar")
var c2: Credentials? = ("foo", nil)

print("cast:", c1.flatMap({ $0 as? (String, String) }))
print("cast:", c2.flatMap({ $0 as? (String, String) }))

if let (u, p) = c1 as? (String, String) { print("if:", u, p) }
if let (u, p) = c2 as? (String, String) { print("if:", u, p) }

NotificationCenter.default.reactive.notifications(forName: notification)
    .filterMap({ $0.object as? Credentials })
    .filterMap({ $0 as? (String, String) })
    .observeValues({ print("signal:", $0) })

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notification, object: c1)
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notification, object: c2)
```