# How to test equality of Swift arrays of named tuples

Tags: swift

Swift tuples are not Equatable, and as compound types, they can't be made Equatable through protocol extension.  The workaround ([as documented in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487519/how-to-elegantly-compare-tuples-in-swift)) is to create an overload for the `==` operator for each arity of tuples.

Interestingly, one can declare the `==` operator for regular tuples and use it to compare tuples with named fields:

```
func ==<T1: Equatable, T2: Equatable>(lhs: (T1,T2), rhs: (T1,T2)) -> Bool {
    return lhs.0 == rhs.0 && lhs.1 == rhs.1
}

var one = ("One", 1)
let two = ("Two", 2)
print(one == two) // "false"

typealias NamedTuple2 = (name: String, value: Int)
var namedone: NamedTuple2 = (name: "One", value: 1)
let namedtwo: NamedTuple2 = (name: "Two", value: 2)
print(namedone == namedtwo) // "false"
print(namedone == one) // "true"
```

Arrays of tuples also need a custom overload to be compared as a whole:

```
func ==<T0: Equatable, T1: Equatable>(lhs: [(T0, T1)], rhs: [(T0, T1)]) -> Bool {
    if lhs.count != rhs.count {
        return false
    }
    for (index, value) in lhs.enumerate() {
        if !(value == rhs[index]) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

let array12: [(String, Int)] = [one, two]
let array3: [Tuple2] = [("Three", 3)]
print(array12 == array3) // "false"
```

However, this operator doesn't accept an array of named tuples:

```
let namedarray12: [NamedTuple2] = [namedone, namedtwo]
let namedarray3: [NamedTuple2] = [array3[0]]
print(namedarray12 == namedarray3)
// error: binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two '[NamedTuple2]' operands
```

Is there a way to test equality of arrays of named tuple, without declaring an overload of `==` for the particular named tuple?

Answer (score 12):

The method `SequenceType.elementsEqual(_,isEquivalent:)` accepts a predicate for comparing elements.  The same `==` overload works for both named and unnamed tuples.  So instead of trying to apply `==` to the arrays as a whole, use `elementsEqual`.

```
func ==<T1: Equatable, T2: Equatable>(lhs: (T1,T2), rhs: (T1,T2)) -> Bool {
    return lhs.0 == rhs.0 && lhs.1 == rhs.1
}

let namedarray: [(name: String, value: Int)] = [(name: "One", value: 1), (name: "Two", value: 2)]
// namedarray == namedarray12
namedarray.elementsEqual(namedarray12, isEquivalent: ==) // true
```

Comment: The tuple equality function is now officially part of Swift as of 2.2. See https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0015-tuple-comparison-operators.md

Comment: @LukasKubanek There is a tuple equality function but tuples are still not Equatable even in Swift 4.2.

Comment: This answer works perfectly in Swift 4.2.1 except that the last line should be:
namedarray.elementsEqual(namedarray12, by: ==)