# How to compare "Any" value types

Tags: swift

I have several "Any" value types that I want to compare.

```
var any1: Any = 1
var any2: Any = 1

var any3: Any = "test"
var any4: Any = "test"

print(any1 == any2)
print(any2 == any3)
print(any3 == any4)
```

Using the == operator shows an error:

> "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'Any' (aka
>   'protocol<>') operands"

What would be the way to do this ?

Comment: How can you compare things you know nothing about? Why are you making them `Any`?

Comment: Im just testing swift capabilities.

Comment: @theReverend `===` compares references, so it can only be applied to reference types - which all of them conform to `AnyObject`

Comment: @Wain, You can compare two things that you know nothing about by asking them to compare themselves. I suspect that the idea is that if the two things are structs then the content needs to be compared but if they are class objects then a content compare or a reference compare might be needed. This might come into play when writing a generic that can hold class objects, structs, or "native" types like Int.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The only way to do this is with a function other than `==` that takes a type parameter, and then compares the values if they are both of that type:

```
func isEqual<T: Equatable>(type: T.Type, a: Any, b: Any) -> Bool {
    guard let a = a as? T, let b = b as? T else { return false }

    return a == b
}
```

Now, using your variables above, you can compare them like this:

```
var any1: Any = 1
var any2: Any = 1

var any3: Any = "test"
var any4: Any = "test"

isEqual(type: Int.self, a: any1, b: any2)      // true
isEqual(type: Int.self, a: any2, b: any3)      // false
isEqual(type: String.self, a: any3, b: any4)   // true
```

Comment: Shmart! But is it neccessey to pass 'type', looks like it's not used anywhere.

Comment: i believe it is necessary despite not using it.  Swift requires you to "use" the generic parameter in some part of the signature.  however, couldn't you just cast `a` and `b`  to `Equatable` directly?

Comment: @MichaelVoline it is used, in the first line of the function. The inputs are casted as the given type, and if either fails then they are considered to be not equal. If the type casts succeed then equality is determined by the == function which is implemented for that type. The point is that it only makes sense to compare two values of the same type, so we have to verify first that they are the same type. But if you didn't give the type to the function then the only other possible implementation would be to type cast to _every_ type that there is until one of them succeeds, which is impossible

Answer (score 17):

You can do it like this by using `AnyHashable`:

```swift
func equals(_ x : Any, _ y : Any) -> Bool {
    guard x is AnyHashable else { return false }
    guard y is AnyHashable else { return false }
    return (x as! AnyHashable) == (y as! AnyHashable)
}

print("\(equals(3, 4))")        // false
print("\(equals(3, equals))")   // false
print("\(equals(3, 3))")        // true
```

As not every `Equatable` has to be `Hashable`, this might fail under rare circumstances.

Usually there is no reason for using above hack; but sometimes you will need it, just as sometimes `AnyHashable` is needed.

Comment: It's fine to use. It's just not any different than Aaron Rasmussen's answer (see my answer for why), and it's not written as Swiftily.

Comment: It is very different from Aaron's answer, as it introduces `AnyHashable`, which is basically compiler magic. Once you know that, you can of course write this in any form you like, for example in the form you wrote it in, also using `AnyHashable`.

Comment: To make the difference more clear: Aaron's answer says, you cannot do what you want to do, you need to use a type parameter for that. My answer says, you can actually do what you want, just substitute `AnyHashable` for the type parameter. I think answers cannot get much more different than that 

Comment: Just because `AnyHashable` is more likely to work than any other type, when the desired  `==` overload is unknown,  it's no so wonderful as to be worth using as an invisible default. Especially without documentation! With Aaron's, you can use `isEqual(type: AnyHashable.self, a: any1, b: any2)`.

Comment: `AnyHashable` is the only **interesting type** that will work. With the help of compiler magic. Otherwise, you know the type already, and then there is no problem in the first place. The problem is, you don't know anything about the type of `Any`, how do you compare two values of type `Any` for equality? The only practical solution to this problem involves `AnyHashable`.

Comment: Now, you can do all sorts of additional non-relevant acrobatics as you do in your solution. I have no problem with that, just don't advertise it as better, because it isn't. In fact, your solution is a complication of my solution, not an extension of Aaron's.

Comment: Seems like there is a need for an AnyEquatable which would make this work in all cases.

Answer (score 4):

To use `==` operator, type has to conform to `Equatable` protocol. `Any` protocol does not conform to `Equatable` protocol, so there is no way to compare two `Any` values. It's logical - `Any` is too broad term - values can have no 'common denominator'.

What's more, Swift doesn't allow to compare two `Equatable` values which have different type. E.g. both `Int` and `String` conform to `Equatable` but `1 == "1"` does not compile. The reason for that is the declaration of `==` in `Equatable` protocol: `func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool`. This Self basically means that both arguments have to have the same type. It it's kind of a placeholder - in implementation for specific type, `Self` should be replaced with the name of this type.

Comment: what if I don't know type of objects to be compared? Is it possilbe to declare any "common type which allows comparison"? In objective-C it was simpler - all (or most) objects have common parent `NSObject` which already supports comparison

Answer (score 4):

Aaron Rasmussen's answer can also be used as an extension, transformed to use potentially non-`any Any` arguments, like so:

```swift
public extension Equatable {
  /// Equate two values of unknown types.
  static func equate(_ any0: some Any, _ any1: some Any) -> Bool {
    ((any0, any1) as? (Self, Self)).map(==) ?? false
  }
}
```

```swift
let int: some Any = Int.random(in: .min...(.max))
let bool: any Any = Bool.random()

XCTAssertTrue(Int.equate(int, int))
XCTAssertTrue(.equate(bool, bool))
XCTAssertFalse(.equate(int, int))

XCTAssertTrue(AnyHashable.equate(bool, bool))
XCTAssertFalse(AnyHashable.equate(bool, int))

struct Equatable: Swift.Equatable { }
XCTAssertTrue(Equatable.equate(Equatable(), Equatable()))
```

Comment: Pretty elegant code, it compiles and all, but when I tried to replicate it didn't work 

Comment: What is "replicate"? The test passes…

Comment: Use it in my project. In my case the tests fails 

Comment: @MauricioChirino It never should have failed to begin with, but I just edited it. Please delete your comment if you get a chance.

Answer (score 4):

There's much more elegant way available in Swift 5.7. It doesn't require to provide a specific type and is suitable for using with generics. Credits to this [blog](https://nilcoalescing.com/blog/CheckIfTwoValuesOfTypeAnyAreEqual/):

```
extension Equatable {
    func isEqual(_ other: any Equatable) -> Bool {
        guard let other = other as? Self else {
            return other.isExactlyEqual(self)
        }
        return self == other
    }
    
    private func isExactlyEqual(_ other: any Equatable) -> Bool {
        guard let other = other as? Self else {
            return false
        }
        return self == other
    }
}

func areEqual(first: Any, second: Any) -> Bool {
    guard
        let equatableOne = first as? any Equatable,
        let equatableTwo = second as? any Equatable
    else { return false }
    
    return equatableOne.isEqual(equatableTwo)
}
```

Comment: very nice solution. Also works in Objective-C code as expected.
What I would add is in **areEqual** method when **guard** fails check if both parameters aren't nil.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve it in the following way

```
enum SwiftDataType
{
    case String
    case Int
    case Int64
    case Double
    case Bool
    case Undefined
}

func getType( of : Any ) -> SwiftDataType
{
    if let type = of as? String
    {
        return SwiftDataType.String
    }
    else if let type = of as? Int
    {
        return SwiftDataType.Int
    }
    else if let type = of as? Int64
    {
        return SwiftDataType.Int64
    }
    else if let type = of as? Double
    {
        return SwiftDataType.Double
    }
    else if let type = of as? Bool
    {
        return SwiftDataType.Bool
    }
    else
    {
        return SwiftDataType.Undefined
    }
}

func isEqual( a : Any, b : Any ) -> Bool
{
    let aType : SwiftDataType = getType( of : a )
    let bType : SwiftDataType = getType( of : b )
    if aType != bType
    {
        print("Type is not Equal -> \(aType)")
        return false
    }
    else
    {
        switch aType  {
        case SwiftDataType.String :
            guard let aValue = a as? String, let bValue = b as? String else
            {
                return false
            }
            return aValue == bValue

        case SwiftDataType.Int :
            guard let aValue = a as? Int, let bValue = b as? Int else
            {
                return false
            }
            return aValue == bValue

        case SwiftDataType.Int64 :
            guard let aValue = a as? Int64, let bValue = b as? Int64 else
            {
                return false
            }
            return aValue == bValue

        case SwiftDataType.Double :
            guard let aValue = a as? Double, let bValue = b as? Double else
            {
                return false
            }
            return aValue == bValue

        case SwiftDataType.Bool :
            guard let aValue = a as?  Bool, let bValue = b as? Bool else
            {
                return false
            }
            return aValue == bValue

        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSObject ...

```
var any1: Any = 1
var any2: Any = 1

var any3: Any = "test"
var any4: Any = "test"

var any5: Any? = nil
var any6: Any? = nil

print(any1 as? NSObject == any2 as? NSObject)
print(any2 as? NSObject == any3 as? NSObject)
print(any3 as? NSObject == any4 as? NSObject)
print(any4 as? NSObject == any5 as? NSObject)
print(any5 as? NSObject == any6 as? NSObject)
```

This should produce :-
true
false
true
false
true

Comment: What if the type is a pure Swift type that does not bridge to an `NSObject` equivalent or a class that does not inherit from `NSObject`?

Comment: I should add a caveat that design your base class to derive from NSObject root object. I am new to Swift but I found that doing so made some of unit test simpler to code. Otherwise you need to know the class name. Also the above only works for Classes & not Structs

Answer (score 1):

There is a semi-private function `_openExistential`, shipped no later than Swift 5.6, that makes this possible.

First, consider the following utilities:

```swift
protocol EquatablePair {
    func perform() -> Bool
}

protocol MaybeEquatablePair {
    func maybePerform() -> Bool?
}

struct Pair<T> {
    var lhs: T
    var rhs: T
}

extension Pair: MaybeEquatablePair {
    func maybePerform() -> Bool? {
        (self as? EquatablePair)?.perform()
    }
}

extension Pair: EquatablePair where T: Equatable {
    func perform() -> Bool {
        lhs == rhs
    }
}
```

Here, we have a conditional conformance of `Pair` to `EquatablePair`. This allows us to use `self as? EquatablePair` to dynamically determine if `T` is `Equatable`. The `MaybeEquatablePair` conformance uses this trick to produce a boolean result if `T` is `Equatable` and `nil` otherwise.

The next part is to get `Pair<T>` for some concrete type `T`. We really need to get `Pair<T>` and not `Pair<Any>`. This is what helps me distinguish this subtle difference: `Any` is nothing but a struct of two fields, one being the pointer to the wrapped value’s type and the other the pointer to the actual value. The reality is slightly more complicated but this should give you some intuition. In this way, `1 as Int` gives you a plain integer, where as `(1 as Int) as Ayn` gives you a special struct, hence `Pair<Int>` is very different from `Pair<Any>`.

So how can we dynamically fetch some `Any`’s wrapped value’s type and use that to get a desired `Pair<T`>? Here comes `_openExisential`:

```swift
func genericEqual(_ lhs: Any, _ rhs: Any) -> Bool {
    func openLHS<LHS>(_ lhs: LHS) -> Bool {
        if let rhs = rhs as? LHS {
            return Pair(lhs: lhs, rhs: rhs).maybePerform() ?? false
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    return _openExistential(lhs, do: openLHS)
}
```

`_openExisential` takes a wrapped value and use it to call some generic function. This magic function will dynamically fetch the type for its first argument and use that to call the generic function dynamically. This is not possible using plain Swift, in which calls to generic functions must have types resolved statically.

`_openExisential` can do more than `Any`. You might have heard the term existential types. This function can, well, open existential containers. It is a very complicated topic. See the Swift Evolution proposal [Implicitly Opened Exisentials](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0352-implicit-open-existentials.md) if you are interested.

My code is simplified from Foundation’s implementation for AttributedString. They seem to have a set of utilities to call Equatable, Encodable, Decodable implementation for `Any`s. Check out [AttributedString.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Sources/Foundation/AttributedString/AttributedString.swift) and [AttributedStringAttribute.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Sources/Foundation/AttributedString/AttributedStringAttribute.swift) for more. Start with struct `CheckEqualityIfEquatable`.

Comment: Getting segfault while trying to compile this (`swift-driver version: 1.62.15 Apple Swift version 5.7.2 (swiftlang-5.7.2.135.5 clang-1400.0.29.51)`)

Answer (score 0):

From Swift 5.7 we can cast values to `any Equatable` and also use `any Equatable` as a parameter type. Based on this there is a simple generic operator `==` to compare `Equatable` instances are wrapped by `Any` type which includes: optionals, arrays, dictionaries etc.

```swift
fileprivate extension Equatable {
  func isEqual(to: Any) -> Bool {
    self == to as? Self
  }
}

func ==<T>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool where T: Any {
  guard let lhs, let rhs else {
    return lhs == nil && rhs == nil
  }
  
  if let isEqual = (lhs as? any Equatable)?.isEqual {
    return isEqual(rhs)
  }
  else if let lhs = lhs as? [Any], let rhs = rhs as? [Any], lhs.count == rhs.count {
    return lhs.elementsEqual(rhs, by: ==)
  }
  else if let lhs = lhs as? [AnyHashable: Any], let rhs = rhs as? [AnyHashable: Any], lhs.count == rhs.count {
    return lhs.allSatisfy { $1 == rhs[$0] }
  }
  return false
}
```

Lets test:

```swift
// Int
let int1: Any = 1
let int2: Any = 1
int1 == int2 // true

// [Int]
let array1: Any = [1, 2, 3]
let array2: Any = [1, 2, 3]
array1 == array2 // true

// Enum
enum Enum {
  case one
  case two
}
let enum1: Any = Enum.one
let enum2: Any = Enum.one
enum1 == enum1 // true

// Struct
struct S: Equatable {
  let i: Int
}
let struct1: Any = S(i: 10)
let struct2: Any = S(i: 10)
struct1 == struct2 // true

// [Any]
let arrAny1: Any = [1, "2"]
let arrAny2: Any = [1, "2"]
arrAny1 == arrAny2 // true

// Any? with nil
let optNil1: Any? = nil
let optNil2: Any? = nil
optNil1 == optNil2 // true

// Any? with Int?
let optInt1: Any? = 2
let optInt2: Any? = 2
optInt1 == optInt2 // true
```