# Check element in array with different objects

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an `array` with custom objects by 2 types. Also I have `TableView`, which shows objects from array. I need to select `tableViewCell` and check, if the element already in array - remove it from array, otherwise add it to array. I know, there is method for the checking `array.contains(element)` but my array looks like `[Any]` and it doesn't have this method.

I'm trying to check it with use `for-in`, but it's not good solution.

How can I do this?

```
let a: Int = 5
let b: String = "3"
let array: [Any] = [a, b]
```

Comment: think you need to conform your custom objects to equatable

Comment: check solution there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778950/how-to-compare-any-value-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to cast `Any` to `Int` or `String` type and just use `array.contains`

```
array.contains {
    if let intValue = $0 as? Int {
        return intValue == 3
    } else if let stringValue = $0 as? String {
        return stringValue == "3"
    }
    return false
}
```

**OR** use this extension (*Swift 4*):

```
extension Array where Element: Any {
    func contains<T: Equatable>(_ element: T) -> Bool {
        return contains {
            guard let value = $0 as? T else { return false }
            return value == element
        }
    }
}


array.contains("3") // true for your example
```

Comment: in example only 2 base classes, but in my code this is 4 or more custom classes

Comment: @SergeyHleb I have just added extension for array, use this extension for any your custom type.

Comment: let me few minutes, I check this

Comment: I'm trying your suggestion, but there is `Use of unresolved identifier 'array'`. I doing something stupid thing like: `(_ element: T, array: [Any])`, and in call it looks like: `addingDevices.contains(device, array: addingDevices)`, but it works perfect, thank you.

Comment: I understood it, okay.

Comment: Replace `array.contains` with `self.contains` in `extension`. Otherwise no benefit in making of `extension`.

Comment: I already doing this, thank you. But I have one more question, if element already in array, how can I remove it? I don't know it's position

Comment: @TheTiger thank you, I've missed this. We are able to use just `contains` without `self`, so I have just fixed this.