# No Equatable out of the box in swift for a struct

Tags: swift, equatable, swift5.6

I've declared my struct to conform to Equatable

```
struct LocationInfo: Equatable {

    // MARK: - Properties

    let gatewayId: GatewayId?
    let gatewaySerialNumber: String?
    let locationId: LocationId
    let locationName: String
    let role: UserRoleModel
    var rooms: [RoomInfo]
    let gateways: [GatewayInfo]
    var devices: [any DeviceInfoProtocol]
    let devicesGroups: [DeviceGroupsInfo]
    let membershipId: MembershipId?
    let partners: [PartnerConnection]
    let scripts: [AutomationScript]
```

all the types used are either String typealiases or Equatable or Hashable entities.
All of them (I've checked and doublechecked). Why do I get

> Type 'LocationInfo' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'

and am therefore forced to implement == ?

Comment: The problem is the `any`. Just because two types conform to the same protocol and both conform to Equatable doesn’t mean they can be compared to each other.

Comment: You may triple check, if actually _all_ types conform to `Equatable`. Based on own experience ;)

Comment: Joakim, would you explain as to a 6 year old: any reason something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778950/how-to-compare-any-value-types does not come out of the box for any?

Comment: Check the subtypes for conformance, if you’ve made custom keys check for typos but “any” can require conformance but doesn’t actually conform.

Comment: The compiler only synthesises the equality function by conforming to `Equatable` if the operands have the _identical_ type. The type `[any SomeProtocol]` does not conform to `Equatable`. It does not, because `any SomeProtocol` does not conform to `Equatable`.  `any SomeProtocol` cannot because it's an "existential" and its wrapped value does not have the requirement to be of the same or a specific type.

Comment: Do you really need the *lazy* way that the compiler does all work for you or could two instances be equal for example if `LocationId` and `name` are equal? The *default implementation* is rather convenient but implementing `==` yourself and comparing one ore two properties can be much more performant (this applies also to `Hashable`).

Comment: If you maje `struct LocationInfo2: Equatable {}` and put one per one (or n per n) to find the culprit maybe?