# How to find the index of a tuple element from an tuple array? iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, tuples

This is inside tableview cellforrowatindexpath

```
    var valueArray:[(String,String)] = []
    if !contains(valueArray, v: (title,status)) {
                let v = (title,status)
                valueArray.append(v)
            }
```

This is inside didselectrowatIndexPath

```
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(selectedRow!)
    var newTuple = (cell!.textLabel!.text!, cell!.detailTextLabel!.text!)
    let index = valueArray.indexOf(newTuple)
```

But i am not getting the index. It is throwing an error cannot convert value of type '(String,String)' to expected argument type '@noescape ((String,String)) throws -> Bool'. What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: I think your issue is Swift doesn't know how to natively compare your tuple for equality. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487519/how-to-elegantly-compare-tuples-in-swift

Comment: Don't store tuples in arrays. Create a struct or object. And yes, you need to consider the test of equality

Comment: Also, why isn't `valueArray(selectedRow)` the one you are after?

Comment: @Paulw11 didnot get you.

Comment: @sschale yeah i know the issue, thats why trying to find a solution

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tuples can be compared for equality (as of Swift 2.2/Xcode 7.3.1), but
they do not conform to the `Equatable` protocol. Therefore you have
to use the predicate-based variant of `indexOf` to locate a tuple
in an array. Example:

```
let valueArray = [("a", "b"), ("c", "d")]
let tuple = ("c", "d")
if let index = valueArray.indexOf({ $0 == tuple }) {
    print("found at index", index)
}
```

In **Swift 4** the method has been renamed to `firstIndex(where:)`:

```
if let index = valueArray.firstIndex(where: { $0 == tuple }) {
    print("found at index", index)
}
```

Comment: actually it can also work like contains function if we use an else statement ;)

Answer (score 6):

Here is my option to find index of tuples

```
var tuple: [(key: String, value: AnyObject)] = [("isSwap", true as AnyObject), ("price", 120 as AnyObject)]
if let index = tuple.index(where: {($0.key == "price")}) {
    print(index)
}
//prints 1
```