# Do Swift Switch short circuit?

Tags: swift, switch-statement, short-circuiting

Do switch statements with more than one evaluations short circuit?

It probably doesn't matter, but I am curious.

---

Here's a simple example:

```
let one = 1
let two = true
let three = false


switch (one, two, three) {
case let (0, b, c) where b==c:
    break

case (0, true, true):
    break

default:
    break
}
```

In the first case statement, will the 'where' evaluation even happen?

In the second case statement, will the 'two' == true happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@J.beenie s answer treats your first question nicely (and convincingly). `b == c` will not be called since your initial `one` does not match `0`, a classical `AND` short circuit.

Your second question depends on the implementation of `==` for tuples. According to [a comment to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487519/how-to-elegantly-compare-tuples-in-swift) this has been part of the Swift-language since 2.2.1 and the standard implementation would of course short circuit since it is the fastest thing to do. So in your second case the second element would not be compared.

Btw: You do not need to `break` in a Swift `switch` statement, instead you would `fallthrough` if you desire otherwise.

**Correction:**
My guess proved to be only half correct. Pattern matching in `switch` statements seems to do more than I expected. I tried to hijack `==` using my own `Bool` enum (roughly following [this post](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=8) (and adjusting for Swift 3)) and got some surprising results:

```
import Cocoa

let one = 1
let two:MyBool = .myTrue
let three:MyBool = .myFalse
typealias ThreeTuple = (o:Int, tw:MyBool, th:MyBool)
let tuple:ThreeTuple
tuple  = (one, two, three)

switch tuple {
case let (1, b, c) where b == c:
   print("first case")    
case (1, .myTrue, .myFalse):
    print("second case")
 default:
    print("default")
}

enum MyBool : ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral, Equatable  {
    case myTrue, myFalse
    public init() { self = .myFalse }
    public init(booleanLiteral value: BooleanLiteralType) {
        self=value ? .myTrue : .myFalse
    }
}

func ==(lhs: MyBool, rhs: MyBool) -> Bool {
    print("evaluate ==")
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case (.myTrue,.myTrue), (.myFalse,.myFalse):
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

which yields

```
evaluate ==
second case
```

at which point I was majorly surprised. The sole evaluation of `==` for `MyBool` values originates from the `where b == c` clause in the first `case` and all the tuple "comparisons" do not use the `MyBool` `==` function *at all*!! I suspected the optimiser was interfering so I turned the `switch` into a `func` as

```
func match(_ tuple:ThreeTuple) {
    switch tuple {
     case let (1, b, c) where b == c:
        print("first case")
     case (1, .myTrue, .myFalse):
        print("second case")
     default:
        print("default")
    }
}
```

which should preclude excessive optimisation at compile time, but when I now ask for

```
match((1, .myTrue, .myTrue))
match((1, .myTrue, .myFalse))
match((0, .myTrue, .myFalse))
```

I get

```
evaluate ==
first case
evaluate ==
second case
default
```

where the `evaluate ==` still originate only from the first `case`. So the only reasonable conclusion seems to be that there is "some other magic" going on during pattern matching in `switch` statements. I tried to google if I could figure out what that was, but to no avail so far. In any way, there seems to be *way* more short circuiting than I would have expected.

Comment: It be cool to write some code to prove second case statement also short circuits. Cant figure out how to do it though.

Comment: @J.beenie you are right, there seems to be something else going on, pattern matching seems to be *really well optimised* (TM) in Swift. Lets see if there is someone who can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1):

Test your question with the following code:

```
let one = 1
let two = true
let three = false


switch (one, two, three) {
case let (0, b, c) where b - c:
    break

case (0, true, true):
    break

default:
    break
}

extension Bool{
    static func - (lhs: Bool, rhs: Bool) -> Bool {
        print("foo")
        return lhs == rhs

    }
}
```

in a playground

just change the first 0 to a 1 and see what happens.

The answer is Yes ;) it does short circuit.